Is there a tool that can print out a bash script with the variables substituted?
Say I have a bash script that takes some environment variables and parameters and substitutes those variables in a script.
Is there a tool that can show how the script with the substituted variables will look like?
Take this short script for instance.
echo user = $USER host = $HOSTNAME

The program would output echo user = vfclists host = unixse
So the script would be along the lines of
expandscript script.sh --param1=xxxx --param2=xxxx --param3=xxxx and in addition to the environment variables filling the values of the params where they are set to the programs variables.

This may not be exactly what you want, but you could run your script with sh -x script.sh and then see each line that is executing with the variable already substituted.

This would only be possible in the simplest of cases (probably not helpful as the outcomes would be so obvious). As soon as your script sets variables within conditional expressions, or from user input, or from the output of another command, the script has to actually execute to show the true values. You might try plentiful debug after every variable assignment (conditional on a single variable that you can enable from the command line). You might add a --dry_run option to avoid it executing lines that may be destructive if there are errors in the variables.

For simple cases maybe you just want envsubst? This will render any text file with variable references replaced with actual values.

@chedieck I have this in some of my scripts, but I'd rather see how the static script looks like.

You can probably get most of what you want using envsubst (part of GNU gettext). It runs simple environment-variable expansion over its input.

The simplest usage would be:
$ envsubst < test.sh
echo user = andrew host = mybox


You can run it with different environment-variables to change the expansions:
$ USER=shrdlu HOSTNAME=universe envsubst < test.sh
echo user = shrdlu host = universe


And you can limit which variables it tries to expand:
$ envsubst '$USER' < test.sh
echo user = andrew host = ${HOSTNAME}



Note that by default it will try to expand anything that looks like a variable. That will include shell-variables whose value is defined within the script. These will be expanded to an empty string if there isn't a corresponding environment-variable defined.
Other potential problems:

I don't think there's a way to tell envsubst to expand command-line arguments ($1).
Currently, envsubst doesn't understand more complicated things like Shell Parameter Expansion.

Alternatives:
You might want to give some more information about what specific problem you are trying to solve, but you might want to see what's going on when you run your script.
If you want to see all the variable-expansions when the script runs, you can enable execution trace (see Debugging Bash Scripts - Bash Guide for Beginners). For example sh -x ./test.sh will echo each line with variables (shell and environment) expanded. You set a PS4 prompt to tie the output back to source line numbers:
$ PS4='$(printf ":%04d: " ${LINENO})' bash -x ./test.sh
:0001: echo user = andrew host = mybox
user = andrew host = mybox

I've not tried this, but it's worth noting that bashdb provides support (with limitations) for stepping through your script as it runs.
